# Did Q ever break the 4th wall?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager

I just figured, as it never happens in Star Trek, it would just add a bunch to Q if he did; it would have demonstrated that he is an omnipotent being.

I don't expect him sitting on a balcony, smoking cigars with a (former) captain of the Enterprise while discussing the fact that their show was moved from Tuesday to Wednesday, but still... I just feel this would suit his character and powers very well. Yet I can't recall him ever doing that.

So I'm asking the community. Did Q ever break the 4th wall?

Yeah, I could have thought of this 20 years ago. Sometimes I am slow. :-)

Comment: Nope. But several people did...; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Fourth_wall

Comment: I think there was an episode with two Qs chasing each other (or playing hide-and-seek?) and the whole ship was briefly turned into a Christmas tree ornament.

Comment: I don't think any of those examples from the website are convincing.

Comment: In the non-canon computer game, Star Trek: Borg, I think there's a part where Q addresses the audience.

Comment: @Joe L. - You're thinking of the *Voyager* episode [Death Wish](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Wish_(episode)), in which a member of the Q continuum called "Quinn" briefly changes the starship Voyager into a Christmas ornament. I'd say this was another "leaning on the fourth wall" example since none of the characters were explicitly aware they were on a show, but in any case it wasn't done by Q himself.

Comment: I don't see how the Christmas tree scene is a near-example of breaking the fourth wall. The audience was never almost acknowledged. Breaking the fourth wall requires more than an actor to simply face towards the camera.

Comment: @T-1000's Son - I think it was a winking reference to the "Star Trek Hallmark Ornaments" that were sold at the time and which were in the shape of various starships. If so, a reference to a real-world tie-in product seems like it would count as "leaning" on the fourth wall though not actually breaking it since the scene would still make sense without knowledge of the product.

Comment: Not actually sure it would increase his sense of power. His identity as an omnipotent being depends in part on him operating within a real universe, one in which his power is real. Breaking the 4th wall basically breaks that sense and replaces a god with an actor.

Comment: And here I was expecting at least one comment about the BL reference. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think he ever clearly broke the 4th wall in the sense of acting as though he was aware he was a character on a TV show. But this line from ["All Good Things..."](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/277.htm) was the closest I found:

> Q: Oh, but it is, and we have. Time may be eternal, Captain, but our patience is not. It's time to put an end to **your trek through the stars**, make room for other more worthy species.

Of course you don't have to interpret this as Q being aware he's on the show "Star Trek", I took it as just a little [title drop](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TitleDrop) by the writers in keeping with this episode's feel as a grand closing statement on the show, but it is at least [leaning on the fourth wall](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LeaningOnTheFourthWall).

edit: Thanks to @T-1000's Son for pointing out that there is a fourth-wall-breaking moment in the (non-canon) game [*Star Trek: Borg*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Borg). The complete set of scenes in the game can be seen in these six videos: [one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjQJKfG_p2o), [two](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH2gKNYFrvk), [three](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTcREwF67co), [four](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SinkMJGHTQ4), [five](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LT5W4XN1WJM), [six](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TY0BfrmhzAg). In part 5, at about 6:10 in, there's a moment where the player character makes a foolish choice and Q (in the guise of a Borg) seems to give up on the player, saying "ugh, I think I need to renew myself in some alternate reality...c'mon everybody, let's go. Such an amateur." Then he walks off with the other characters as the dramatic music cuts out and suddenly we hear what sound like the voices of the film crew in the background (they speak in ordinary-sounding English even though the scene is set on a Borg ship), as if the director just called "cut". After that Q comes back and says "oh, all right", snaps his fingers, and the player character gets to go back to an earlier stage before they made the bad choice.